# How to Activate ENV Created By Virtualenv Having Conda Installed

Tags: virtualenv, conda

So I have conda installed first, then Virtualenv, on Windows 10.

Now both tools use "activate env" to activate envs created. I found conda's activate function overrides virtualenv's (could be vice versa in theory).

I'd like to find out how to choose which activate to use. Or at least, how to activate env created by virtualenv. Thanks!

Comment: You should not try to mix virutalenvs and conda environments. Just use conda environments, its what they're there for.

Comment: Thanks @darthbith ! I'm new to conda. The reason why I'm running both is that I use vanilla python with an IDE (MyEclipse + pydev), and I have no idea how to make IDE working with different environments created by conda. Any thougths?